# PHP Prepare statement error

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   /home/melazabi/public_html/assigment/The/include/process.php on line
>   15

```
// check if the username exists in the database
// line 15 is the one below:
$statement = $conn->prepare("select * from users where username=? AND password=?");
//prepare statment is to try to stop sql injection
$statement->bindParam(1, $un);
$statement->bindParam (2, $pw);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: Show the code that sets `$conn`

Comment: How are `$un` and `$pw` defined?

Comment: $un = $_POST["username"]; $pw = $_POST["password"];

Comment: And your form elements are named? I.e.: `name="username"` and `name="password"`

Comment: if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
// get the username and password entered by the user
$un = $_POST["username"];
$pw = $_POST["password"];

// check if both fields are not empty
if($un&&$pw)

Comment: <?php
session_start();

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','admin','admin')  or die("error2");
mysql_select_db("admin") or die("error");
?>

Comment: not those, the codes for your HTML form is what I was talking about.

Comment: There's the problem `mysql_connect` you need to connect using PDO

Comment: How and where `$un` and `$pw` are set is secondary to the problem with `$conn`

Comment: Use something like `$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);` because you're presently using `mysql_connect` with a PDO query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per what you shown in [`your comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231892/php-prepare-statement-error#comment33758605_22231892):

You're using a `mysql_*` based connection

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','admin','admin') or die("error2"); mysql_select_db("admin") or die("error");
```

with a PDO query.

You need to use: (replace with actual DB credentials)

```
$dbname = 'admin';
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'admin';

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: You're quite welcome, glad we were able to resolve this. Cheers @Mattlinux1

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you the your query failed for any number of reasons.

1. Your db connection failed, either authentication problem or complete failure to connect.
2. Your params are not defined correctly.

you can debug this by

```
 print_r($statement->errorInfo());
```

this will give you what the error returned by sql was.

also make user variables are set.  If i were to guess not having seen the rest of your code. you probably want $_POST['un'] and $_POST['pw']

```
 echo $un;
 echo $pw;
```

edit

connect to db:

```
 $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='SERVERADDRESS';dbname=DBNAME;charset=utf8', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
```

then your query

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("select * from users where username=? AND password=?");
//prepare statment is to try to stop sql injection
$statement->bindParam(1, $un);
$statement->bindParam (2, $pw);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: The odd thing is that it works with this line of code but not the prepare statement. $statement = mysql_query("select * from users where username='$un'");

Comment: as Fred pointed out, it looks like you are combining PDO and mysql syntax.  see my edit in a second.

Comment: I will +1 this because we were on the same "wavelength" ;-) and probably at the same time. (lol) cheers